# DOM Error in EXTJS

Tags: extjs

While running an EXTJS code,i got an error. `Error : DOM is null or not an object.` What does this error mean?

Comment: You need to show us your code and/or preferable a working link where we can investigate the error. This way we might be able to tell you why you get this error.

Comment: @chau: i tried to upload the code.but it exceeded the limit.the file is 'ext-all.js'.

Comment: We don't want ext-all.js.  Your code is causing ext-all.js to fail because something has been done improperly in your source code.

Answer (score 2):

First, switch your page to use ext-all-debug.js.  This makes the code more readable and will hopefully give you a better idea of what the ExtJS framework is doing when it barfs on your code.

Since you have not provided any source code of yours, I suggest using Firefox with an add-on called Firebug for starters.

Firebug allows you to debug Javascript, css, html, and general issues you may have in your page.  Using firebug, use the stack trace to see what object or dom-ID's are having problems.  This will allow you to troubleshoot your own code.

You can also place breakpoints in your scripts and follow what is happening.

Answer (score 0):

The most likely cause is you have an event registered either directly accessing the `dom` property or calling a method which does so, and that event fires before the component is rendered.

Answer (score 0):

I've had that error before as well, turns out in my case it was a config in the view called shim, it was set to true, so I set it to false and never got that error again.